# Varnish won't start correctly

Tags: apache, webserver, varnish

I have a problem by starting varnish. It always starts with default-parameters but I want varnish to be listening to port 80. It seems that the init-script won't run varnish correctly (start-stop-daemon) and then it runs with defaults. My daemon.log gives me sourcecode from varnish, if I start. I use newest Debian Version 8.7, installed it with apt-get install varnish. If I start varnish without Init-Script everything's fine: /usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m (works)

My config and logs:

```
/etc/varnish/default.vcl:
it's default, nothing changed

/etc/default/varnish:
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
         -T localhost:6082 \
         -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
         -S /etc/varnish/secret \
         -s malloc,256m"

Start Init-Script
root@albiorix:~# /etc/init.d/varnish start

/var/log/daemon.log:
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix systemd[1]: Starting Varnish HTTP accelerator...
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: /* ---===### include/vcl.h ###===--- */
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: /*
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: * NB:  This file is machine generated, DO NOT EDIT!
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: *
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: * Edit and run generate.py instead
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: */
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: struct vrt_ctx;
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: struct req;
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: struct busyobj;
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: struct ws;
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: struct cli;
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: struct worker;
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: typedef int vcl_init_f(struct cli *);
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: typedef void vcl_fini_f(struct cli *);
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: typedef int vcl_func_f(const struct vrt_ctx *ctx);
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: /* VCL Methods */
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: #define VCL_MET_RECV#011#011#011(1U << 1)
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: #define VCL_MET_PIPE#011#011#011(1U << 2)
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: #define VCL_MET_PASS#011#011#011(1U << 3)
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: #define VCL_MET_HASH#011#011#011(1U << 4)
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: #define VCL_MET_PURGE#011#011#011(1U << 5)
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: #define VCL_MET_MISS#011#011#011(1U << 6)
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: #define VCL_MET_HIT#011#011#011(1U << 7)
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: #define VCL_MET_DELIVER#011#011#011(1U << 8)
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: #define VCL_MET_SYNTH#011#011#011(1U << 9)
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: #define VCL_MET_BACKEND_FETCH#011#011(1U << 10)
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: #define VCL_MET_BACKEND_RESPONSE#011(1U << 11)
...
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: static struct director#011*directors[2];
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: const struct VCL_conf VCL_conf = {
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .magic = VCL_CONF_MAGIC,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .init_vcl = VGC_Init,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .fini_vcl = VGC_Fini,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .ndirector = 2,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .director = directors,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .ref = VGC_ref,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .nref = VGC_NREFS,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .nsrc = 2,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .srcname = srcname,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .srcbody = srcbody,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .recv_func = VGC_function_vcl_recv,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .pipe_func = VGC_function_vcl_pipe,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .pass_func = VGC_function_vcl_pass,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .hash_func = VGC_function_vcl_hash,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .purge_func = VGC_function_vcl_purge,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .miss_func = VGC_function_vcl_miss,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .hit_func = VGC_function_vcl_hit,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .deliver_func = VGC_function_vcl_deliver,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .synth_func = VGC_function_vcl_synth,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .backend_fetch_func = VGC_function_vcl_backend_fetch,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .backend_response_func = VGC_function_vcl_backend_response,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .backend_error_func = VGC_function_vcl_backend_error,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .init_func = VGC_function_vcl_init,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: .fini_func = VGC_function_vcl_fini,
Feb  2 13:57:13 albiorix varnishd[24822]: };
Feb  2 13:57:14 albiorix systemd[1]: Started Varnish HTTP accelerator.
(1177 lines)

processes (ps ax):
24351 ?        SLs    0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
24352 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m

root@albiorix:~# varnishd -V
varnishd (varnish-4.0.2 revision bfe7cd1)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2014 Varnish Software AS
```

I hope you can help me or simply can tell me why there's sourcecode in my logfiles :-/.
Thx to the community 
Beneboy

PS: Sorry for my english, I'm german. So please answer in german if you can :-).

Answer (score 1):

config /etc/default/varnish is no longer used with systemd in debian 8.

Edit this file: /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service

reload systemd: systemctl daemon-reload

restart varnish: systemd restart varnish.service

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

thx Christophe :-)

I would have read the info in the file more precisely:

```
Headerinfo in der /etc/default/varnish:
# Note: If systemd is installed, this file is obsolete and ignored.  You will
# need to copy /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service to /etc/systemd/system/ and
# edit that file.
```

:-/